# Accessing data from more than one table - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Do tables have to be joined to extract data from them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you mean in one query.  There are two ways I can think of to extract data for more than one table in a single query without "joining" them:

Fist is with union

```
SELECT A, B, C FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT X, Y, Z FROM Table2
```

You can also do a "cross join" which does not look like a join (and is probably what you are thinking of)

```
SELECT Table1.A, Table1.B, Table1.C, Table2.X, Table2,Y, Table2,Z
FROM Table1, Table2
```

As you can see from the syntax there is not relationship from one table to the other.  This means that **every row in table1 will be combined with every row in table2!**

In my experience this is the most common mistake that programmers new to SQL make.  They do a cross join when they mean a join and then they GROUP BY or DISTINCT to get the results they want.  This is hugely inefficient!

Cross join can be good however, especially when you one of the table has just one row -- then you are adding those values to every row in other table.  You are basically selecting single set of values for columns for every row.

Like if you want every row to have the maximum date (this is often done in reports)

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM Table1, (SELECT MAX(updatedate) as Max_Update FROM Table1) AS MaxDate
```

Comment: @Justin - yw, make sure you check the edits, I added usage notes about cross joins.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily, there are other options like Union:

```
SELECT customerNumber id, contactLastname name
FROM customers
UNION
SELECT employeeNumber id,firstname name
FROM employees
```

the above example is take from [this.](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-union-mysql.aspx)
There are other times you can run multiple queries, etc to get data from multiple sources with out a join. It all depends on what you want to do.  However, join is a very common--and probably most usual--approach.